# RQuantLib OSX installation issue

Tags: r, macos, rjdbc

followed the steps below to install QuantLib on OSX and it went smoothly:

http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml

Then trying to install RQuantLib. First download the source, unzipped and executed the following command from Terminal, with the error messages below:

```
$ R CMD INSTALL RQuantLib
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
```

Tried directly in R, same issue:

```
> install.packages("RQuantLib")
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RQuantLib’ had non-zero exit status
```

Tried reinstalling RJDBC in R, no success either. Somehow I can't get this to work, and am stuck now.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Se my step-by-step post on installing RQuantLib [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477507/rquantlib-and-mac-os-x-10-8-2/36388457#36388457).